# Verify the contract from a contract factory directly from React

Tags: web3js, etherscan, ethers.js, react, hardhat

I am learning about web3 and using web3-react, ethers and hardhat. I made a contract, and I want that every user deploys their own Contract. The deployment function is this:

```
async function deployMyContractContract(signer: Signer): Promise<void> {
  const myContractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(
    NFTCollectionArtifact.abi,
    NFTCollectionArtifact.bytecode,
    signer
  );

  try {
    const myContract = await myContractFactory.deploy(...contractArguments);

    await myContractFactory.deployed();


    window.alert(`nftColletion deployed to: ${myContractFactory.address}`);

  } catch (error: any) {
    window.alert(
      'Error!' + (error && error.message ? `\n\n${error.message}` : '')
    );
  }
}
```

The Contract deployment is just fine. However, the Contract is not verified yet. So what is the best way to verify it on EtherScan or PolygonScan?
If I deploy one Contract with the same ABI and verify, all the other copies would be automatically verified?